# ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException for the Doctrine entity associated with "User"

Tags: symfony5

I have this problem, I forgot to put the link in the twig template while testing the password reset, I can't delete the user because I have this error, what can I do now?
thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please add your user entity file to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset-password Entity

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
```

Solution :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $user;
```

This has allowed me to delete the user in the database.